# wrong result of aggregation pipeline in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation

I am new To NodeJS and MongoDB. I want to fetch data from the multiple table using aggregation pipeline. SO My table structure is like this :

### Category :

```
_id, category_name, ...
```

### Product :

```
_id, product_name, category_id, ...
```

### purchase :

```
_id, buyer_id, product_id, price, ...
```

I want to get all product list like this :

### Expected Result :

```
{
   _id : "1",
   product_name: "abc",
   category : {
      category_name: "xyz"
   },
   purchased : {
      buyer_id: "101",
      price : "$10"
   }
}
```

### My Aggregation pipeline is like this :

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "category_id": "627f8118a9ef34edc9be1f51"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "category_id": {
        "$toObjectId": "$category_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "categories",
      "localField": "category_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "category"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$category"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "purchases",
      "let": {
        "main_product_id": "$_id",
        "product_buyer_id": "627f7cf5a9ef34edc9be1f41"
      },
      "as": "purchase",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "product_id": {
              "$toObjectId": "$product_id"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$product_id",
                    "$$main_product_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$buyer_id",
                    "$$product_buyer_id"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$purchase",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  }
]
```

If I run this pipeline in mongo-compass softwere then It's return expected result. But when I run this same pipeline in NodeJS Code, It does not return `purchase` object in result.

I am facing this problem from last 5 days Can't find The Problem Yet. Can anyone please help me. Any kind of small help would be great help for me.

Thank You.

Comment: purchase, purchases, purchased. Please check the spelling

Comment: there is no difference in query processing between node, compass or anything else. I vote that something wrong with your data